# DateDiff years into decimals

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datediff

I have two dates in which i would like to find the number of years between them, however i would need to show the value to two decimal places.  I have tried the following but i always get a value returned of 0 as all of my dates do not cover a whole year:

```
DATEDIFF(yy, @EndDateTime, i.mat_exp_dte)
```

I have then tried finding the number of days between the two and then dividing it by 365, but this still returns 0:

```
DATEDIFF(dd, @EndDateTime, i.mat_exp_dte)/365
```

Am confused now as to how to calculate this.  Would i need to convert the DataDiff into a different data type?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
DATEDIFF(dd, @EndDateTime, i.mat_exp_dte)/365.0
```

Dividing int with an int returns int. Divide with a decimal and you will get a decimal as a result.

Comment: what is the command in sql to cut(! - not round) decimal places ? (lets say 2) ? 1.12345 --->1.12

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Last try :) `select round(1.19999, 2, 1)`

Comment: select  CAST (  round(1.19999, 2, 1) AS numeric(3, 2))........but i think its too long...:)

Comment: This wouldn't take in to account leap years. Its a small adjustment but would still need to be factored in.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a more accurate version of this that accounts for leap years, then you can do this instead:

```
cast(DATEDIFF(dd, @EndDateTime, i.mat_exp_dte) as float)
/datediff(dd,@EndDateTime,dateadd(yy,1,@EndDateTime))
```

Comment: Great answer! This is what I was looking for several times. Glad I found it. To everyone: don't do stuff like dividing by 365.2524 because it is not right. This answer is.

Answer (score 2):

.0 stands for floating point number, hence calculations include decimals. Without it you calculate integer division.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
(YEAR(@EndDte) - YEAR(@StartDate) + 
(MONTH(@EndDate) - MONTH(@StartDate) /100.0 + 
(DAY(@EndDate) - DAY(@StartDate) /10000.0)
```

If you need to determinate if there is exactly one year, less then one, or more than one. (=1, <1, >1)